# Gatsby starter for howtographql site

Tags: gatsby

I like the https://www.howtographql.com/ site. It looks to be based on Gatsby. I was wondering if there is a starter to create a similar site? Looking in the [community starters](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-starters/) list I'm not sure what would be the best one to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The source for How to GraphQL is [available here](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql). You can check that out. I'd suggest going through the [official tutorial series](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/) to get started.

Comment: yes, I had considered that but then I can't really update to new features/bug fixes as things change. I guess there is no reusable template like their site.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Any starter/theme for Gatsby is the structure and potentially styling/added plugins, but the core is uncoupled. Short of a large version bump (like v2), updating your dependencies to the latest version of Gatsby will cover any bug fixes/new features. Even if you used one of the available starters, there's no "upgrade" path like that of a Wordpress theme. They merely give you an opinionated foundation.